# {Is dir} and mkdir in separate folders

Tags: php, tcpdf, mkdir

I need to check if a folder exist in an other folder. If not, then a new folder will be created. I can´t seem to get it to work. See code below.

Note: I use TCPDF.

```
// Create filename
$filnamnet = $id.'_'.$datum.'_'.$fornamn.'_'.$efternamn.'.pdf';


// Folder in iup_pdf
$mapparna_dir = 'iup_pdf/'.$id.'_'.$fornamn.'_'.$efternamn.'_'.$personnummer.'';

// Check if folder exist in iup_pdf
if(!is_dir($mapparna_dir) ) { 
   mkdir('iup_pdf/'.$id.'_'.$fornamn.'_'.$efternamn.'_'.$personnummer); 
}

$pdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/iup_pdf/'.$id.'_'.$fornamn.'_'.$efternamn.'_'.$personnummer.'/'.$filnamnet.'', 'F');
```

The error states: TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this of use.

```
function RecursiveMkdir( $path=NULL, $perm=0644 ) {
    if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
        RecursiveMkdir( dirname( $path ) );
        mkdir( $path, $perm, TRUE );
        clearstatcache();
    }
}
```

I tend to find that the fullpath works best - ie:$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/elements/to/folder' etc rather than the relative path. Also, is_dir() determines if a file is a directory - perhaps use file_exists as in the function.

> `if( !file_exists( $mapparna_dir ) ) RecursiveMKdir( $mapparna_dir );`